# Show multi-login popup when user is loggedin in multiple google account and bypass the login popup if user is loggedin in only one accout

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth, google-api-javascript-client

I am working to add google sign-in flow on web app. Trying to figure out if we can achieve this functionality,

1. if user is logged-in in multiple google account, show the multi-login popup where user can choose the account.
2. if user is logged-in in only one google account and has previously signed into the application, bypass the login page and direct them to the application.

I thought `auth2.signIn`, it checks to see how many accounts are present, and based on this it achieve those above use-cases.

As further context, the javascript for the login page code is currently:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init_google_signin" async defer></script>
<script>
function init_google_signin() {
        var auhtInstance,
            clientID = 'client_id';

        auhtInstance = gapi.load('auth2', function () {
          /**
           * Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the
           * client.
           */
          auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: clientID,
            scope: 'email profile'
          });
        });
      }
</script>
```

Further the google sign-in button click handler is written as,

```
function handleGoogleSignIn() {
    var GoogleAuth,
        currentUser,
        googleAuthPromise;

    GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    currentUser = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();

    if (currentUser && currentUser.isSignedIn()) {
       // submit form with access_token and user info, service will redirect user to logged-in page
       setGoogleFormValues(currentUser, currentUser.getBasicProfile());
    } else {
       googleAuthPromise = GoogleAuth.signIn();
       googleAuthPromise.then(function (user) {
          // submit form with access_token and user info, service will redirect user to logged-in page
          setGoogleFormValues(currentUser, currentUser.getBasicProfile());
       });
    }
}
```

To Fix this, i tried,

1. when user logging-out from app, logout from google `GoogleAuth.signOut();`
2. when user clicks on google sign-in button, revoke access first then it will always prompt the login popup `GoogleAuth.disconnect();`
3. use `prompt: 'select_account'` while signin, so handleGoogleSignIn will look like,

   ```
    function handleGoogleSignIn() {
       var GoogleAuth,
           currentUser,
           googleAuthPromise;

       GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
       currentUser = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();

       googleAuthPromise = GoogleAuth.signIn(prompt: 'select_account');
       googleAuthPromise.then(function (user) {
          // submit form with access_token and user info, service will redirect user to logged-in page
          setGoogleFormValues(currentUser, currentUser.getBasicProfile());
          });
       }
   }
   ```

These all three fix always open the popup so it fixed the 1st use case but failed on 2nd use case.

I would really appreciate thoughts on how to achieve both use cases.

Many thanks!

Comment: to bypass the account selection, you need to add login_hint. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: If i do that, this will fix the bypass thing but 1st (multi popup issue) will remain unfix.

Comment: of course you only use a login_hint when it's a returning user. You have to code for this yourself.